# OneNote alternative that can import OneNote notebooks

Tags: software-recommendation, alternative

I am aware that alternatives to OneNote has been discussed before, but from what I can see none of these alternatives allow you to take you OneNote notes with you as you migrate. I have a lot of notes that I wish to keep, so many that manual transfer is impractical.

So the question is: Are there any OneNote alternatives, that lets me take my notebooks with me as I migrate?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

## UnMHT

Adds Mht file reading/writing support to Firefox.

Mht (Mhtml) is the webpage archive format to store Html and images, Css into single file.

[Web site](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8051)

UnMHT provides following features:

- Save webpage as Mht file.
- Save selection as Mht file
- Insert URL of the webpage and date you saved into saved Mht file.
- Save multiple tabs as Mht files at a time.
- Save multiple tabs into a single Mht file.
- Save webpage by single click into prespecified directory with QuickSave feature.
- Convert Html files and directory which contains files used by the Html into Mht file.
- View the Mht file saved by UnMHT, IE, PowerPoint, etc.

## Export in OneNote

Allows you to save a file under a different name or location.

- Click or tap the File tab and select Export.
- The Export Current pane appears at right.
- If using a keyboard and mouse, you can Ctrl+click multiple pages to export multiple pages in the same file.
- Select Page or Section, choose the format you want for exporting, and click or tap the Export button.
- The Save As window appears, indicating that the concept of saving versus exporting hasn’t quite made it to all interface elements yet.
- You must chose `Single File web Page` This format uses the Mime Html document format .mht, which saves an entire web page in a single file.
- Click or tap Save to export the file.

*Note: If you select Notebook to export, you can choose Portable Document Format, this format uses the .pdf extension and is compatible with any device that supports Pdf.*

Answer (score 0):

I've spent some time looking into this, and I haven't found anything decent. I have found that if you email yourself a copy of your notebook, it inserts the notebook text into the body of the email.

You  could also install OneNote on your computer using [Wine](http://winehq.com). The 2010 version works quite well, or so their website states [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2911).